# Chrome get image height issue when tabsload, although use .load function

Tags: jquery, image, google-chrome, height, jquery-ui-tabs

some images (such as 4 picture with each different height) inside a TabContent, I wrote

```
$('#Tab').tabs({.......}); 
// Tab function is not the point, its fine.

$('#TabContent').ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('.bookCover').removeAttr('height');
    $('.bookCover').each(function() {
        var h;
        h = this.height;
        $(this).height(h);
        alert($(this).height());
    });
});
```

and the result is 130, 0, 0, 0. (only the first one can get the real height)

how to get the height in Chrome. When I am using Tabsload.

I have tried to use

```
$('.bookCover').load(function() {
    // ........
    $(this).height(h);
    alert($(this).height());
});
```

but still can get once TabContent data loaded.

click the tab again, then TabContent is not correct with height.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that elements which are hidden by `display: none` have no height attribute.

I've created a [demonstration fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NnKHu/)

The best alternative I can think of is to clone the image to a position off screen (say `left: -3000px`) and set `display: block` on it, and then get its height.

Comment: Actually, this is because Chrome too fast to renders the image, and JS detected zero pixel width and height of the image.